# Fill NaN values when two columns have same switched values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
Groups NAME1            NAME2              VAL1 VAL2
G1     Canis_lupus      Cattus_cattus      NaN  NaN 
G1     Homo_sapiens     NaN                39   78
G1     Cattus_cattus    Canis_lupus        56   67 
G3     Populus_nigra    Arabidopsis_tha    2    89 
G3     Arabidopsis_tha  Populus_nigra      NaN  NaN
```

And I would like for each `NAME1 == NAME2` matching values to fill the corresponding `VAL1 VAL2 NaN` values.

for instance `Canis_lupus` and `Cattus_cattus` are mates, then I use the `VAL1` and `VAL2` from `row3` to fill the one in `row1`.

In the exempel I should fill NaN with the mates such as ;

```
Groups NAME1            NAME2              VAL1 VAL2
G1     Canis_lupus      Cattus_cattus      56   67
G1     Homo_sapiens     NaN                39   78
G1     Cattus_cattus    Canis_lupus        56   67 
G3     Populus_nigra    Arabidopsis_tha    2    89 
G3     Arabidopsis_tha  Populus_nigra      2    89
```

Does someone have an idea please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to check `np.sort`, then groupby with new column along with `Group`

```
df[['new1','new2']] = np.sort(df[['NAME1','NAME2']].fillna('').values,1)
up = df.groupby(['Groups','new1','new2'])[['VAL1','VAL2']].apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
df.update(up)
df.drop(['new1','new2'],1,inplace=True)
df
Out[59]: 
  Groups            NAME1            NAME2  VAL1  VAL2
0     G1      Canis_lupus    Cattus_cattus  56.0  67.0
1     G1     Homo_sapiens              NaN  39.0  78.0
2     G1    Cattus_cattus      Canis_lupus  56.0  67.0
3     G3    Populus_nigra  Arabidopsis_tha   2.0  89.0
4     G3  Arabidopsis_tha    Populus_nigra   2.0  89.0
```

Answer (score 3):

One way that works here is to use `groupby.transform` with `first`. And to do the groups, you can `agg` the two name columns with `frozenset`.

```
df[['VAL1','VAL2']] = (df.groupby(df[['NAME1', 'NAME2']].agg(frozenset, axis=1))
                         [['VAL1','VAL2']].transform('first')
                      )
print(df)
  Groups            NAME1            NAME2  VAL1  VAL2
0     G1      Canis_lupus    Cattus_cattus  56.0  67.0
1     G1     Homo_sapiens              NaN  39.0  78.0
2     G1    Cattus_cattus      Canis_lupus  56.0  67.0
3     G3    Populus_nigra  Arabidopsis_tha   2.0  89.0
4     G3  Arabidopsis_tha    Populus_nigra   2.0  89.0
```